Shared class inheritance
While I am aware this is weird, I still want to know if it can work mainly for improving understanding.
Basically, it is inheriting a class, but also from the parent class being able to call methods in the sub class.
An example of the issue is as follows:

class Match:
    player = Player(...)
    # other things here

class Player:
    def __init__(self, name, etc)
        ....
        self.display = Display(self)

class Display(Player):
    def __init__(self, player):
        super().__init__(player.name,...)


The goal of this is to call self.player.display.method() from Match to help separate out the display functionality of Player with all the other methods.
Currently the way it is done above leads to recursion between Player and Display.
This is simply fixed by removing the Display class and flattening the methods into Player. But I don't want to do that. The other option would be to find a way to stop the super().__init__ in Display before it gets to self.display potentially with a flag variable, but I didn't get this to work.
In my solution I would like:

Display to be able to access all of the instance data and methods in Player so self.name would work in Display for example, without having to call self.player.name or manually assigning self.name
Player to call methods in Display
Effectively creating a shared class between the two, purely for aesthetic reasons.

I have tried going through super() documentation and articles such as https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/
Used guard conditions, such as if not from_super: self.display = ...
Suspect might be able to use hasattr to detect super invoke but didn't get this to work

Display does not sound like the name of a class that should be inheriting from Player at all.

self.player.display.method() does not require any sort of inheritance relationship between Player and Display, any more than it requires such a relationship between Match and either of those classes.

I'm aware it doesn't require it, but for the Display method it needs 90% of the variables and a few of the methods in Player so hence, I used it.
The situation is producing an output from the match after everything else has been calculated

Display needing "90%  of the variables" of a player, doesn't change that a Display is not a Player. Keep a player instance as an attribute of Display, if that makes sense, and if the problem is typing self.name instead of self.player.name, just attribute self.player to a local variable in the begining of your display methods - player = self.player  - and then you do player.name.
Other than that when there is a real use for inheritance, the way for a superclass to call a method in subclasses, is just call then - the overriden method in the subclass will be used. One can either create stubs for these methods, or make an abstract base class - or not at all, and just document the needed methods in subclasses.
For example, you could have class UserControledPlayer(Player): and class BotPlayer(Player): in this project, each of which would have a distinct def move(self, ...):  method.
